# Function Consultar produto inicial e final

Tags: jquery, ajax

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de exportações para gerar um relatório de produtos por ciclo e área de baixa. Porém eu preciso filtrar entre produto inicial e produto final, no caso, tenho um function para fazer essa consulta, mas ela só se aplica ao produto inicial.
Como posso fazer para implementar essa consulta também para o produto final?

Segue código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: O que seria PRODUTO INICIAL e PRODUTO FINAL?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer dizer com inicial e final. Seria Filtrar o código entre inicial e final? Por exemplo: O código é um ID (ex: 5) e você quer filtrar os produtos com código entre 4 e 6?